# Cannot create container for service peer0.org2.example.com: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Wehenever trying to start the test network by making docker-compose test network up the below error is receive.

Cannot create container for service peer0.org2.example.com: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters

################## CODE ##########################

peer0.org2.example.com:
container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
labels:
service: hyperledger-fabric
environment:
#Generic peer variables
- CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=fabric_test
- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
#- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
- CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
- CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=false
- CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
- CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
- CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
# Peer specific variables
- CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
- CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9051
- CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9051
- CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9052
- CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9052
- CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:9051
- CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.example.com:9051
- CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
- CORE_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:19051
**volumes:
- ${DOCKER_SOCK}:/host/var/run/docker.sock
- ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
- ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
- /var/pavan/peer0-org2:/var/hyperledger/production**
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
command: peer node start
ports:
- 9051:9051
- 19051:19051
networks:
- test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your `DOCKER_SOCK` variable is empty.

You can try with a volume like...

```yaml
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
```

...instead of the first one.

Comment: The error is resolved but could not observe docker containers are up for those multiple peers.